# How can fixup dbforge problem in codeigniter -4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

When I am trying to insert new column using codeigniter version 4 with dbforge.

I got an error in Production mode:

> Whoops!We seem to have hit a snag. Please try again later...

```
public function addLanguage()
{ 
    $language = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/', '', $this->request->getPost('language',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));

    $language = strtolower($language);

    if (!empty($language)) {

        if (!$this->db->fieldExists($language, "language")) {

            $this->dbforge->addColumn("language", [
                $language => [
                    'type' => 'TEXT'
                ]
            ]); 

            $this->session->setFlashdata('message', 'Language added successfully');

            return redirect()->route('backend/setting/language');
        } 

    } else {
        $this->session->setFlashdata('exception', display('please_try_again'));
    }
    return redirect()->route('backend/setting/language');
}
```

What am I doing wrong in this code? Any potential help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Development mode error image below:
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of `display('please_try_again')`, you could display the actual error message and you would know what went wrong. This logic is fine in a production code, but not in a development version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code

```
public function addLanguage()
    { 
        $dbforge = \Config\Database::forge();
      
        $language = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/', '', $this->request->getPost('language',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));

        $language = strtolower($language);
        if (!empty($language)) {
            if (!$this->db->fieldExists($language, "language")) {
  
                
                $dbforge->addColumn("language", [
                    $language => [
                        'type' => 'TEXT'
                    ]
                ]); 

                $this->session->setFlashdata('message', 'Language added successfully');
                return redirect()->route('backend/setting/language');
            } 
        } else {
            $this->session->setFlashdata('exception', display('please_try_again'));
        }
        return redirect()->route('backend/setting/language');
    }
```